# ATL Metamodel contains several classifiers with same name error

Tags: java, bpmn, emf, ecore

I have a small ATL program converting BPMN2.0 to another model as:

```
-- @nsURI MM1=http://www.my.site/path/to/my/MM1
-- @nsURI BPMN20=http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL-XMI
-- @path reo=/BPMN20reo/reo.ecore
rule definition2module {
    from
        b: BPMN20!Definitions
    to
        m: reo!Connector(name<-b.name)
}
```

module test;
create OUT: reo from IN: BPMN20;

The code generates the following errors. I believe it has something to do with loading/finding BPMN 2 model. I tried also using the BPMN 2 file address but still I get the following errors:

Metamodel contains several classifiers with same name: DocumentRoot
Metamodel contains several classifiers with same name: DocumentRoot
Metamodel contains several classifiers with same name: di::DocumentRoot
Metamodel contains several classifiers with same name: DocumentRoot

Here is my code https://github.com/behnaaz/BPMN2ATL

Comment: The generated output is also empty: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI"/>

Comment: Do you know what "di" is in "di::DocumentRoot"?

Comment: Zelus: This is an example of bpmndi as I mentioned before it is for the diagram info  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">

Comment: Did you validate the ecore metamodels?

Comment: It is coming from the bpmn 2 plugin directly. Do I need to validate it?

Comment: I'd try validate both the input and output metamodel to ensure that they don't have validation problems.

Comment: There is no problem with the meta models.

Comment: I'll set up a github project and share the whole project.

Comment: I validated the ecore models and there were no error. Here is my code https://github.com/behnaaz/BPMN2ATL

Comment: I have downloaded the code and try to execute the transformation. I found that the model newDiagram_1.bpmn is not conform to the metamodel BPMN20, for example the root element (definitions) in the metamodel is defined as Definitions and ATL can run the transformation. After resolve the previous error I found that the Definitions metamodel in your model contains and attribute process that the Definitions elements in the metamodels not contains.

Comment: On the other hand when you work with ATL is necessary that one of the rules generes in the output only one elements that is the root element of model and the remaining elements are childs of the root element.

Comment: Thanks Victor. I appreciate your help. I don't think the input which is generated by a BPMN 2 tool is incompatible with the model. Definitions is an instance of rootElement which contains flowElements which process is an instance of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is what is Meta-model schizophrenia - two loaded models for one purpose.
It seems more than one BPMN 2 class is registered.

I uninstalled all BPMN 2 related plugins from Eclipse, so the only meta-model there was my own meta-model in the project.

Comment: I also suspect that because BPMN2 has dependency to three other ecore things are a bit more weird with it. Any thought?

Comment: Also not all BPMN2 provide XMI files that are read well by ATL. It seems ATL fails to read them without any error or warning.